# Change of mouse cursor too fast when saving less data

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cursor

`"cursor", "wait"` only shows when i save many item on the database, however, if i only add one data,changing of `"cursor", "wait"` to `"cursor", "default"` doesnt not show because the process is too fast.
this is how i set my cursor image : Is there anything that i can code,so the changing of cursor will be seen by the GUI user even he saved only one item(saving too fast csenario).

```
 $(".save").click(function() {
        $("body").css("cursor", "wait"); 
      save();
});


function save(){
           ///saving to database and other happens here
           $("body").css("cursor", "default");
           //end of saving process here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can save items to database only using ajax method from javascript. So,

```
$( document ).ajaxStart(function() {

    $("body").css("cursor", "wait"); 

 });

$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
       $("body").css("cursor", "default"); 

 });
```

Comment: ajax is new to me, so i dont know how to use it. how can i  add this to my current code above? can you give me example using this?

Comment: without ajax knowledge, how can you save items in database using javascript or jquery?.

Comment: without ajax knowledge, how can you save items in database using javascript or jquery?. can u please say, In which way you are using save items in database?

Comment: i pass table data using servlet sir,and use hibernate mapping

Comment: sorry i don't know about servlet, but you try this code i am not sure it works for you.  Your code is:                              $(".save").click(function() {
        $( document ).ajaxStart(function() {
   $("body").css("cursor", "wait"); 
  }).ajaxComplete(function() {
      $("body").css("cursor", "default"); 

   });
});

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
 $(".save").click(function() {
        $( document ).ajaxStart(function() { $("body").css("cursor", "wait"); }).ajaxComplete(function() { 
              $("body").css("cursor", "default"); 
        });

     });
```

Comment: i think this is working find but i have it to change save").click(function() {
        $( document ).ajaxStart(function() { $(".save").css("cursor", "wait"); }).ajaxComplete(function() { });, because it only works in body so sometimes i have to moved the cursor, is their anything like $("html").css("cursor", "wait"); ?